# Static site generator with Yeoman generator-webapp capabilities

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, yeoman, browser-sync, static-site

All the static site generators (SSGs) I have tried still feel like a downgrade compared to the frontend development workflows I have with e.g. [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) or [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). **Do you know of a SSG that** besides for the usual features:

- write posts in Markdown
- style the theme layout in some template language (e.g. EJS)

also **offers the level of usability as the Yeoman generators like generator-webapp provide?** Some features generator-webapp includes are:

- CSS Autoprefixing
- Built-in preview server with BrowserSync
- Automagically compile Sass with libsass
- Automagically lint your scripts
- Map compiled CSS to source stylesheets with source maps
- Awesome image optimization
- Automagically wire-up dependencies installed with Bower
- The gulpfile makes use of ES2015 features by using Babel

It's simply a joy to work with generator-webapp compared to the SSG workflows. I am also talking about modifying the SSG blog theme too – the post writing in Markdown is usually ok-ish for most SSGs (though e.g. adding D3 to show a nice visualisation in a post wouldn't be as smooth).

SSGs that I've tried like Jekyll, Hugo or even Node-based Hexo do provide some basic live reloading and even pre-processors. Still, they do not allow you to e.g. write scripts in ES6, pull in a recent bower package and have it be automatically linked to the site to do a small demonstration of some new technology in a blog post. This would be possible in something like [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) or [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp), but these on the other hand lack the Markdown processing, theme layout creation with template tags and partials etc.

[Harp.js](http://harpjs.com/) looks promising, as it provides the SSG-blog-like functionality and there are attempts to integrate it [with BrowserSync](http://charliegleason.com/articles/harp-gulp-and-browsersync) or [Yeoman generators](https://github.com/dzaharia1/generator-harp), but it is still far from ideal. Perhaps some sort of [composed](http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html) generator combining Harp and the most recent generator-webapp could be created to combine the best of the frontend web development and SSG blogging workflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after quite a bit of exploration and trying out different static site generators, I found the [Jekyllized](https://github.com/sondr3/generator-jekyllized) Yeoman generator that wraps some gulp, browsersync etc. magic around Jekyll to be the smoothest approach.

There seems to be some progress on a [Hugo Yeoman generator](https://github.com/sondr3/generator-hugo) from the same author, but it seems to be work in progress at the time of writing.

Additionally, you can add [jekyll-compose](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-compose) for some basic post/page/draft management from the command line.